# question about charge pump circuit

Tags: power-supply, voltage, charge-pump

My charge pump circuit is giving increased Vload in simulator, about 22v.

but when I breadboard and test, with Vsupply from a 12V power supply, multimeter shows Vload about 11v.

I've tested changing parts of same model but still getting same voltage so I think my parts is working.

what might be reason?

Is there anything I should know about choosing my parts? power level of resistor, etc.

---

So I tested and C7 not charging, C13 charges though, what is causing error

---

oops, I missed resistor 1.5k. Now I can get 20 volt

[image: mycircuit]

Comment: Your C7 is backwards in the schematic, is this how it is on the actual circuit?

Comment: I breadboarded just as schematic. So C7 is opposite? but still give 22V both side in simulator. I will try reversing C7 in actual circuit

Comment: Try increasing the value of your load resistor (R3) to see what happens.  I think that your oscillator frequency is far too low to supply 22 mA to the load.  Also note that 22V is the theoretical value you will get.  In practice, it will be significantly less, depending upon load current.

Comment: I increased Rload to 10K, still same voltage. but I tested removing C7 and still same voltage, which means C7 is weird? So I changed C7 capacitor, but still same voltage

Comment: So I tested and C7 not charging, C13 charges though, what is causing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first order of business in checking out the real circuit is to see if the 555 output is able to maintain a reasonably good looking square wave with full swing from near GND to up near the VCC level of 12V. If the output cannot achieve this then there is no hope to be able to step the voltage up as you wish. The output should have an aquare waveform with a 50% duty cycle at a frequency of about 45kHz.

If the output is acting up then you need to make sure that you have GND hooked up to the 555. Also check out the VCC (+12V rail). Is it staying nice and steady at the 12V level? If the +12V level is sagging way down then there will little chance of doubling the output voltage. Make sure that the battery that you are using is not some 3/4 dead unit with a high output resistance.

Comment: My Vout of 555 may be weird because C8 also not charging, and when I probe Vout is just flat. How should I test 555 timer? I tested with LED and LED oscillate lit and off.

Comment: You test it with an oscilloscope, not an LED. Besides with the component values that you show in the schematic the 555 should be oscillating at about 45kHz. There is no way you could distinguish that as on and off lighting of an LED using your eyes.